# Accepted answer styling is a little more vibrant than usual

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Just noticed this on the main page. No hand-drawn circle; let's see if you can pick it out:

[image]

This actually looks rather similar to the styling on Stack Overflow:

[image]

Comment: I think it is kind of ugly.

Comment: Whoops. Fixing.

Comment: Status - [tag:Broken by Anna]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry about that. I was fixing accepted answer indicators in the linked/related questions in the sidebar, and messed up the front page in the process because I am a genius.

Comment: You are a genius.